# android google play libs using too much CPU usage

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to develop an apps with google maps features, so I followed a few tutorials and I realized that making this apps requires the project to use google play service libs library.
But I have problem with the CPU usage when trying to run the project on my AVD which cause the eclipse won't even run the project and keeps loading and I had to force close my Eclipse.

My task manager

[image]

So I tried to pinpoint the problem by making new blank android project and try to run the project as I follow the tutorial step by step.
And I found out that as soon as I add the google play libs to my project, I can't run the project anymore because of the CPU usage problem.

My library used

[image]

I have downloaded the latest verison of the google play service (rev 27) from my SDK manager.

Can anyone please help me? thanks a lot..

Comment: How is your development machine equipped (CPU, memory, ...)

Comment: i'm sorry i don't quite understand what you mean.. do you mean my AVD?
my AVD's CPU use ARM(armeabi-v7a) with RAM 572 and VM Heap 32 and internal storage 200mb

Comment: I meant your computer where you run Eclipse and the AVD.

Comment: My computer use i5-4460 with 3.20GHz CPU and 4GB RAM

Comment: Why don't you use the opportunity and switch to Android Studio? Eclipse always has been just terrible and most likely that problem will disappear one you switch. If it doesn't then there is probably something wrong with your computer.

Comment: thanks for your advice.. i'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved when I stopped using Eclipse and started using Android Studio

Comment: And if you want to use just maps, you should selective compile only the maps package, as discussed here.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project